# Is the ISO 8601 datetime representation precision 1 microsecond in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I was looking at the docs for PostgreSQL, and in the datetime section, the precision for time and datetime is given as 1 microsecond. I want to use this precision in the ISO 8601 precision. In the docs, I also found an example, see `Table 8.11. Time Input` in the doc:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-TIME-TABLE

The example given is `04:05:06.789`. Now my question is, is .789 microseconds? Since it is only 3 digits, it looks like it is in milliseconds. And if so, how can you represent it in microseconds in the format HH:MM:SS.FFFFFF, where FFFFFF are the microseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use three digits it's interpreted as milliseconds. If you use 6 digits it's interpreted as microseconds.

You can use the `MS` pattern for milliseconds and the `US` pattern for microseconds (see [Table 9.24. Template Patterns for Date/Time Formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE)) to check.

```
SELECT to_char('04:05:06.789-8'::time, 'HH12:MI:SS.US'),
       to_char('04:05:06.789000-8'::time, 'HH12:MI:SS.US'),
       to_char('04:05:06.789123-8'::time, 'HH12:MI:SS.US');
```